# Sheets.js (XLSX) não ler no diretorio C: com Electron (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, typescript, electron

o meu problema é simples, porém difícil.
No Main Process tenho: 
**pdfbundle.ts**

```
import XLSX from "xlsx";

export function generatepdf(paths: {xlsxFile: string; savePath: string;}) {

    console.log(paths.xlsxFile);
    // Problem is in this line:
    const file = XLSX.readFile(paths.xlsxFile);
    const sheets = file.SheetNames
    const values = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(file.Sheets[sheets[0]], {
        raw: false
    });
    values.map((e: any) => {
        console.log(e);
        })
}
```

**main.ts**

```
    import { app, BrowserWindow, dialog, ipcMain } from 'electron'
    import { generatepdf } from './hooks/pdfbundle'
    
    let mainWindow: BrowserWindow | null
    
    declare const MAIN_WINDOW_WEBPACK_ENTRY: string
    declare const MAIN_WINDOW_PRELOAD_WEBPACK_ENTRY: string
    
    // const assetsPath =
    //   process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    //     ? process.resourcesPath
    //     : app.getAppPath()
    
    function createWindow () {
      mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        // icon: path.join(assetsPath, 'assets', 'icon.png'),
        width: 1100,
        height: 700,
        backgroundColor: '#191622',
        webPreferences: {
          nodeIntegration: true,
          contextIsolation: true,
          preload: MAIN_WINDOW_PRELOAD_WEBPACK_ENTRY
        }
      })
    
      mainWindow.loadURL(MAIN_WINDOW_WEBPACK_ENTRY)
    
      mainWindow.on('closed', () => {
        mainWindow = null
      })
    }
    async function registerListeners () {
   // HERE CALLS THE FUNCTION
        ipcMain.on('generatepdf', (_, values)=>{
            console.log(values);
            generatepdf(values);
          })
    }
```

E está me retornando esse erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui é o retorno dos consoles (Primeiro é o value do main.ts, o segundo é o primeiro no pdfbundle.ts)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguma sugestão de o que posso fazer a respeito?

Comment: A mensagem diz que tu estás chamando um método `readFile` de uma variável ou constante não definida (não instanciada). Procurei essa chamada e não achei no código que tu postaste. Sugiro que tu faças um debug para identificar o motivo disso.

Answer (score -2):

EUREKA!

A solução foi mais fácil do que eu pensava, mas um pouco confusa para mim (Foi na tentativa e erro que achei a solução), os problemas eram os imports e faltando o set_fs. Conforme a documentação do [sheets.js](https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs)

```
import * as XLSX from "xlsx";
import * as fs from 'fs';


export function generatepdf(paths: {xlsxFile: string;savePath: string;}) {
    // Set filesystem
    XLSX.set_fs(fs);
    //...
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).